# How to add the numbers from a variable in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sum

Sample contents of my variable `$a` is `12 11 45 20 67`. How to sum/add all the above five numbers and store it in another variable called `$b`?

Comment: So `a="12 11 45 20 67"` right ? You can: replace all spaces with `+` sign with `tr`, you will get `12+11+...`. Then pipe the whole string to `bc` command.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But how do i add N numbers of a variable output and store it in another variable?

Comment: If you replace space for `+`, it does not matter how many numbers there are, as long as there's a `+` between every two of them... To store the output of a command use [command substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). For the rest "replace space with `+`" or [use `bc` to calculate in bash](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+bc+to+calculate+in+bash) you can search in google.

Comment: @Kamil you don't need to replace anything. A simple for loop can do the job as per my answer below

Answer (score 2):

without replacing anything

```
a="12 11 45 20 67"
for i in $a; do ((b+=$i)); done ; echo $b
155
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
a="12 11 45 20 67"
abc=' ' read -r -a arr <<< "$a"
b=0
for i in ${arr[@]}; do
  let b+=$i
done
echo "Total: $b"
```

Comment: What purpose does the `abc=' '` have?

Comment: Good point! It's useless. Just posted without cleaning the code before, sorry. Funnily it doesn't break it :D

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) work, a good answer should always explain what the problem is and how it gets solved.

Answer (score 0):

As Kamil noted in the comment you will have to process the contents somehow in order to replace the spaces with plus signs, some possibilities

```
echo "$a" | sed 's/ /+/g'
echo "$a" | tr ' ' +
echo "${a// /+}"
```

Now we have to evaluate this. You can use the `bc` command or the builtin math capabilities of `bash`:

```
echo "$a" | tr ' ' + | bc  # like Kamil suggested 
echo $(( ${a// /+} ))    # bash builtins, probably faster
```

To store the output of a command in a variable use `var=$( command )` like this

```
b=$(echo "$a" | tr ' ' + | bc)
```

Or the faster way which only works for math with bash internals:

```
echo "$a"            # 12 11 45 20 67
(( b = ${a// /+} ))
echo "$b"            # 155
```

Comment: The fact that the bash arithmetic doesn't support floats is worth mentioning.

Comment: why replace spaces with plus signs and not just `for i in $a; do ((b+=$i)); done ` ?

Comment: @funkyjelly because it is more code and it creates the extra variable `$i`. It is also slower.